# Eloquent: How to join a directly related table and a indirectly related table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

To demonstrate my problem, I have created a fictitious database with these 4 tables (defined as Eloquent models): *User*, *Product*, ShoppingItem (short: *Item*), *Order*; with all their relevant relations. (*User* included here only for completeness)
**Products:**

- id
- name
- *hasMany(Item)*

**Orders:**

- id
- user_id
- date
- *hasMany(Item)*

**Items:**

- id
- product_id
- order_id
- *belongsTo(Product)*
- *belongsTo(Order)*

So the (Shopping) *Items* records are created whenever a customer buys some products. An *Order* (the shopping kart) is created as well and contains 1 or more *Items* belonging to exactly one customer (*User*) and his current shopping process.

Now this problem is about the list of products and a way to analyze their 'success'. How often are they sold and **when was the last time one was sold?**

I can, for instance, use the following query to get all *Orders* for a single product and therefore to count how often they are sold:

```
$orders = Order::whereHas('items', function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('product_id', $id) 
          ->where('date', '<', Carbon::now());
})->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();
```

Also, I can get a list of all products ordered by the amount of time they have been sold with this:

```
$products = Products::withCount('items')
                    ->orderBy('item_count', 'desc');
```

**But I want to get a list of all products, sorted by the date when they were last ordered (purchased).** That result must be an Eloquent query or a Query Builder set, so that I can use pagination on it.

I have a Mutator defined in my Product model, like this:

```
public function getLastTimeSoldAttribute( $value ) {

    $id = $this->id;

    // get list of plans using this song
    $order = Order::whereHas('items', function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('product_id', $id) 
              ->where('date', '<', Carbon::now());
    })->orderBy('date', 'desc')->first();

    return $order->date;
}
```

It returns the date of the last purchase of this product and I can use it in the view like this:

```
{{ $product->last_time_sold }}
```

However, I can't use '*last_time_sold*' in an Eloquent OrderBy statement!

Is there another way to get the value of '*last_time_sold*' of a product within the database relationships as described above without losing the ability to do Pagination?

**Ultimately, what is the proper way to query the Products table and order the products by the last time they have been ordered?**

Mind you, the items don't have a date, only the order (the Shopping Kart) has a date.

Comment: if items donot have date how is this `$query ->where('date', '<', Carbon::now());` supposed to work?

Comment: Good question! But for some reason it works... and the 'date' is actually a field of table Orders, whereby 'product_id' is a field of table Items. So in that sub-query it apparently allows me to mix field names from both tables - as long as they have different names, I guess. I'm by no means an expert on Eloquent...

Comment: I can get a list of all *shopping items* with the product details and the actual shopping kart (order) date, ordered by this date like this: `$items = Item::with('product','order')->orderBy('product_id','date')`  but that produces a list of all items, not of all products (which is much smaller).

Comment: Are there any other columns in these tables (specifically the items table)?

Comment: Sure, there are plenty more. These are just the bare minimum to be able to reproduce/demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LEFT JOINs with the `items` and `orders` tables, group by `products` and order by `MAX(orders.date)`.

```
$products = Product::leftJoin('items', 'items.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->leftJoin('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'items.order_id')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->selectRaw('products.*, max(orders.date) as last_ordered')
    ->orderBy('last_ordered', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

This will execute the following query:

```
select products.*, max(orders.date) as last_ordered
from `products`
left join `items` on `items`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
left join `orders` on `orders`.`id` = `items`.`order_id`
group by `products`.`id`
order by `last_ordered` desc
```

**Note 1:** If you only want to get products that has already been ordered - use `join()` instead of `leftJoin`.

**Note 2:** If you run MySQL with strict mode (default for laravel 5.3) you will need to include all columns from `products` table in the `groupBy()` clause.

**Note 3:** For products that have never been ordered the `last_ordered` column will be NULL. In MySQL NULL is ordered first when using `ASC` and last when using `DESC`. But AFAIK this is not documented. So if you don't want to rely on that behaviour, use:

```
->orderbyRaw('max(orders.date) is null')
->orderBy('last_ordered', 'desc')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often you'll be performing this query, it might be better to create a "last_ordered" column for the timestamp on products and touch it each time there is an order.

Comment: You're absolutely right but it's actually not a very frequent query.